# Building tripple from two different data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to to build the triples: source --> target --> edge and Store these triples in a new dataframe.

I have two data frames

```
     Accident_ID Location  CarID_1  CarID_2  DriverID_1  DriverID_2
0            1    Tartu     1000     1001           1           3
1            2   Tallin     1002     1003           2           5
2            3    Tartu     1004     1005           4           6
3            4   Tallin     1006     1007           7           8



    User_ID First Name Last Name  Age           Address  Accident_ID     ROLE
0        1    Chester    Murphy   25  Narva 108, Tartu            1   Driver
1        2     Walter    Turner   26   Tilgi 49, Tartu            2   Driver
2        3      Daryl    Fowler   25    Piik 67, Tartu            1   Driver
3        4        Ted    Nelson   45   Herne 20, Tartu            3   Driver
4        5     Olivia  Crawford   38  Kalevi 25, Tartu            2   Driver
5        1    Chester    Murphy   25  Narva 108, Tartu            2  Witness
6        6        Amy    Miller   27   Riia 408, Tartu            3   Driver
7        7        Tes     Smith   25  Narva 108, Tartu            4   Driver
8        8       Josh     Blake   36  Parnu 37, Tallin            4   Driver
9        3      Daryl    Fowler   25    Piik 67, Tartu            4  Witness
```

The triples which I have to formed is in this pattern
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

what is the python code for this? I have written this one but I am getting error witness is not defined

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='Accident_ID')
df3["train"] = df3.Accident_ID < 5 
df3["train"] .value_counts()

triples = []
for _, row in df3[df3["train"]].iterrows():

    if row["ROLE"] == "Driver":
        if row["User_ID"] == row["DriverID_1"]:
            Drives = (row["User_ID"],row["CarID_1"], "Drives")
        elif row["User_ID"] == row["DriverID_2"]:  
            Drives = (row["User_ID"],row["CarID_2"], "Drives")
    else:    
        Witness = (row["User_ID"],row["Accident_ID"], "Witness") 

    Involved_in_first = (row["CarID_1"],row["Accident_ID"], "Involved in")
    Involved_in_second = (row["CarID_2"],row["Accident_ID"], "Involved in")
    Happened_in = (row["Accident_ID"],row["Location"], "Happened in")
    Lives_in = (row["User_ID"],row["Address"], "Lives in")
    triples.extend((Drives , Witness  , Involved_in_first,Involved_in_second, Happened_in , Lives_in ))


triples_df = pd.DataFrame(triples, columns=["Source", "Target", "Edge"])
triples_df.shape
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data that can be copied, not an image.

Comment: please send me your mail or something where I can send you these data frame files

Comment: I have posted a sample of my dataframe that can be copied @NYCCoder

Answer (score 0):

You should something like this and follow the same process for the rest of the edges:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['Accident_ID'], how='inner')
print(df)
columns = ['Source', 'Target', 'Edge']
rows = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    row1 = [
        df.iloc[i]['First_Name'],
        df.iloc[i]['CarID_1'],
        'Drives'
    ]
    row2 = [
        df.iloc[i]['First_Name'],
        df.iloc[i]['Accident_ID'],
        'Witness'
    ]

    rows.append(row1)
    rows.append(row2)

df_g = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
print(df_g)
```

**Output:**

```
     Source Target     Edge
0   Chester   1000   Drives
1   Chester      1  Witness
2     Daryl   1000   Drives
3     Daryl      1  Witness
4    Walter   1002   Drives
5    Walter      2  Witness
6    Olivia   1002   Drives
7    Olivia      2  Witness
8   Chester   1002   Drives
9   Chester      2  Witness
10      Ted   1004   Drives
11      Ted      3  Witness
12      Amy   1004   Drives
13      Amy      3  Witness
14      Tes   1006   Drives
15      Tes      4  Witness
16     Josh   1006   Drives
17     Josh      4  Witness
18    Daryl   1006   Drives
19    Daryl      4  Witness
```